# Virtual Machines not accessible in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-linux

I am in an organization on azure with the following roles:
[image: roles]

Another member with the same roles created an azure VM that I can not see in my virtual machine interface. It always takes me to this window whenever I search **Virtual Machine**.

[image: search results]

When I access the link shared by the other person to access the page, it will lead me to this error page:

[image]

Having the role of Global admin, should not I be able to access everything in the organization setup?

This is the current license of the organization

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, **Azure AD** roles are different from **Azure RBAC** roles.

You have **Azure AD** roles that will only help you to manage Azure AD resources like users, groups, applications etc., and won't give access for Azure resources.

To manage **Azure resources** like virtual machines, storage accounts etc., you need **`Azure RBAC`** roles that links with subscription.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD user named **`Test user`** and assigned **same roles** as you like below:

[image]

When I signed in with above **`Test user`** account, I got the **same screen** as you like below:

[image]

I got the **same error** as you when I tried to access virtual machine like below:

[image]

You can check with other members what **`Azure RBAC`** role they have under virtual machine as below:

[image]

To ***resolve*** the error, get yourself assigned with the **same RBAC role** the other member has, under your subscription like below:

[image]

After getting that role, you can access the **virtual machine** successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: thanks. I figured it out earlier and it was the same process. I was not added to the subscription that causes the issue.